# Create dataset from xmlfile

Tags: xml

I have the following code

```
           string myXMLfile = @"path to file";
           DataSet ds = new DataSet("myDataset");
           DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("ExtID");
           dataTable.Columns.Add("Ext", typeof(string));
           dataTable.Columns.Add("TargetPath", typeof(string));
           ds.Tables.Add(dataTable);
           ds.ReadXml(myXMLfile);
```

The dataset contains the columns and the amount of rows is correct but they're all empty. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Does the XML contain the values for a single table? Or for a full dataset (multiple tables, with relationships between them)?

If it's a single data table: try loading the XML on the data table instead:

```
dataTable.ReadXml(myXMLfile);
```

Marc

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create the DataTable if your file already has the right columns. Just do:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
ds.ReadXml("FilePath");
```

Once it's loaded you can access the data table at `ds.Tables[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that reads from XML string and reconstructs DataSet in VB.net

```
Public Function StringXMLToDataSet(ByVal XMLString As String) As DataSet
    Dim StringReader As New StringReader(XMLString)
    Dim dset As New DataSet()
    dset.ReadXml(StringReader)
    Return dset
End Function
```